# Is the xml correct for ER diagram

Tags: xml, entity-relationship

I'am trying to convert an ER diagram [ER Diagaram Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QWcrk.png)
To xml with respective xsd. 
Any help/suggestion is really appreciated. Thank you.

**XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<company xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema_instance" xsi:SchemaLocation="companyxsd.xsd" companyname="abc" address="hj">
    <department dname="dfsdf" deptphoneno="1232321" deptfaxno="2323" deptemail="fefsf">
        <employee empid="fsd" ename="fuehuf" emailid="fhueh" phoneno="364764"> </employee>
        <employee empid="fsd" ename="fuehuf" emailid="fhueh" phoneno="364764"> </employee>
        <contractEmployee name="fdsf" phoneno="12345"> </contractEmployee>
    </department>
</company>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's very explicitly complaining about an element named "companyname" and there is no such element in the XML instance that you've shown us, so I strongly suspect you are somehow validating a different XML document from the one you think you are validating.

Comment: But the company name is atrribute for element company. and i have defined it as attribute in LINE 5 of xsd.

Comment: I guess I will have to write it again from scratch. Can you please have a look at the ER diagram and confirm that the xml that I wrote is correct, because I am doing it first time and not so sure.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not familiar with the semantics of this particular XML vocabulary.

Comment: It's Okay. Thank you for reply anyway.!